# How to evaluate TCP variants in Linux

Tags: linux, tcp, performance-testing

There are lots of TCP variants available (bbr, cubic, Westwood, reno) in the Linux. But how to evaluate the performance of these variants? Which are the popular tools used to extract the congestion window and RTT information?

iperf and other similar traffic generator can be used to generate traffic but how to get congestion window and other TCP metric information?

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Asking for tools is not on-topic.

Comment: It mentions that we can ask for "software tools commonly used by programmers". I think it is important for the developers perspective to know the write evaluation tools.

Comment: You can ask *about* tools, like if you have problems with a tool like an IDE or editor then that's okay. But asking for *recommendations* of tools is off-topic. For recommendations see [the Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will keep this in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

For live monitoring sufficiently recent versions of `ss -ti` will be able to extract some debug information, including the congestion window and rtt. For BBR specifically it provides even more information.

Some information can also be inferred from packet captures, e.g. google's rttcp can use tcp timestamp values to determine RTTs.